# How to integrate amazon-ivs-player into flutter Mobile App?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, mobile, media-player, amazon-ivs

I tried aws ivs player integration based on below mentioned docs. but I can't integrate into flutter mobile app.

Docs : Amazon Interactive Video Service Player: SDK for Android Guide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate amazon-ivs-player SDK into flutter Mobile app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740515/how-to-integrate-amazon-ivs-player-sdk-into-flutter-mobile-app)

Comment: no @Jameson ...

Comment: You can add native views to your flutter app. Follow this guide https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-views

Comment: I will check and let you know if i have any issues

Comment: Did you ever manage to do this integration? Can you share some hints or links if so? Thanks!

Comment: Any progress on this one?

Answer (score 2):

AWS currently doesn't have an official Flutter SDK for the IVS Player. To fill the gap, I've created a custom plugin for the AWS IVS Player SDK that you can use in your app. Feel free to check it out and make any modifications you need:

https://github.com/ferns-it/flutter_ivs_player_sdk

Answer (score -2):

```
  final _channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('wss://edge.ivschat.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'),
    headers: {
     
      'Upgrade': 'websocket',
      'Connection': 'Upgrade',
      'sec-websocket-protocol': "your token",
      'Sec-WebSocket-Version': 13
    },
  );
```

It work fine.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.